# SenchaTouch update list with proxy

Tags: list, sencha-touch-2, loading

Hello i have a to do list on my sencha application and i want to add an item at this list.
This list is provided by web service with database data

when i add an item ,i can retrieve him on my database but the list isn't refresh and i don't understand how to do this.

Someone can help me ?

here my list:

```
 config: {
            id:'Listetaches',
            grouped:true,
            store:'PokerStore',
            sorters:'Tache_Libelle',
            itemTpl:'{Tache_Libelle} <br/>  Durée estimé : {Tache_Estimation} h',

            onItemDisclosure :true          
}
```

here my store:

```
  config:{

    model:'PlanningPoker.model.Poker',
    autoLoad:true,
    id:'storeList',
    grouper: function(record){
        return record.get('Tache_Libelle')[0];
    },
    proxy:{
        type:'ajax',
        url:'Myurl',
        useDefaultXhrHeader : false,
        reader:{
            type:'json',    
        },

    },
    autoSync: true,
}
```

here my controller where i add an item

```
 onAddtache: function(button, e, options) {

    var libelle=Ext.getCmp('libelle').getValue();
    var description=Ext.getCmp('description').getValue();


    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'Myurl',
        method: 'POST',
        useDefaultXhrHeader : false,
        params: {
            Libelle: libelle,
            Description:description,
        },
        callback: function(options, success, response) {
            console.log(response.responseText);
            button.up('navigationview').pop();

        }

    });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to reload your store again after adding an item.

Step 1: On your application the store loads the data from the database. (The data is saved locally)

Step 2 :Then you add a new item to your database, but the store still has the data of Step 1.

Add a `store.load()` `or store.sync()` to the callback of your Ajax request

```
callback: function(options, success, response) {
   console.log(response.responseText);
   button.up('navigationview').pop();
   Ext.getStore('PokerStore').load();
}
```